# A component variable not being displayed on the page (Angular6)

Tags: html, typescript, angular6

So the thing is: The html template of an angular component doesn't seem to be aware of the variable i set. Basically even if I set a variable in .ts class and then try to display it in a component, the view behaves as if there was no variable.

I've also tried creating a variable inside a  tag but it just wouldn't work

`TS`
[The ts part of a component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPaI4.png)

```
export class <%component_name%> {
  bar = "test";
  constructor(){...}
}
```

`HTML`
[The html part of a component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMicF.png)

```
<div>
    <div>{{bar}}</div>
</div>
```

[The result is:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lrqC.png)

Just in case: if I type a text inside the div without trying to display a variable, it works

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jI3L7.png)
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZb6q.png)

Oh, just in case: logging the hello variable in constructor function does display it in console: [*click*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkTKB.png)

besides, if I add an *ngIf referencing some boolean from the TS file like that:

`TS`

```
export class <%component_name%> {
  foo = true;
  bar = "test";
  constructor(){...}
}
```

`HTML`

```
<div *ngIf="foo">
    <button>{{bar}}</button>
</div>
```

..then nothing at all is displayed.

At the end it's supposed to be a button with an icon and text on it, but i only get an icon on the button (Which is referenced inside the .html file)

If you have any idea of what might be going on, pls tell

Comment: Your notation is already wrong. You cannot declare a class variable using `var`. Are you sure this is the actual code you are using?

Comment: It is not, I pretty much rewrote it, because the issue only appears on a single component in the whole project and I'm not really allowed to copy the chunks of code from there. You are right though, there is no "var" keyword, but the rest is the same

Comment: From what you posted here, nothing seems to be wrong. Can you provide a reproducible full example?

Comment: There you go, I edited the question so it now has a couple snippets from the actual code, but really I'm not sure if it helps